# Straight Table Borders

Tags: tables, border

I was just wondering whether there was a simple way to make the borders of a table straight?

My code currently is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\textheight=23cm
\textwidth=16cm
\topmargin=-1cm
\oddsidemargin=0cm
\parindent=0mm
\pretolerance=2000
\tolerance=3000
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{T-Test} \\
\hline
  t   & df& Sig. (2-tailed) & 95\% Confidence Interval \\
\hline
 -3.818 &57 & .000& (-11.31082,-3.52834)  \\

\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

My table currently looks like: [image]

Any solutions would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 5):

Add `\usepackage{array}`, it will connect the lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you do not want additional packages, you can correct the tabular manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\textheight=23cm
\textwidth=16cm
\topmargin=-1cm
\oddsidemargin=0cm
\parindent=0mm
\pretolerance=2000
\tolerance=3000
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|  }
\hline\noalign{\null\vspace{-1mm}}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{T-Test} \\[-1mm]
\hline
 t   & df& Sig. (2-tailed) & 95\% Confidence Interval \\[-1mm]
\hline
$ -3.818$ &57 &$ .000$& $(-11.31082,-3.52834)$  \\[-1mm]
\hline
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe math mode in the last line of your tabular.